# Halmos Measure Theory section 16 problem 1

Tags: measure-theory

The problem states:

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure over $\mathbb{R}$. If $E$ is a Lebesgue measurable set such that, for every $x$ in an everywhere dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$
$$
\lambda(E\bigtriangleup (E+x))=0
$$
then $\lambda(E)=0$ or $\lambda(\mathbb{R}\setminus E)=0$

(where $E+x=\{y\in\mathbb{R}:y=a+x, a\in E\}$ and $\bigtriangleup$ denotes the symmetric difference between $E$ and $E+x$).

I think it has something to do with Steinhaus theorem, but I can't figure out how to solve it.